# ng-repeat works in one application, but not the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've been working on two simple Angular apps as part of Free Code Camp, and I am getting mixed results. In the first app, everything seems to be working fine. I make an `$http.get()` call, an array of objects is returned, and I'm able to use `ng-repeat` (key in ARRAY) to populate my page with data. That Pen can be found here: http://codepen.io/StephenMayeux/pen/ZbBgap

My second app is virtually the same (making an API call, this time with Wikipedia) but it uses `$http.json()` instead of GET because `JSONP` (and not CORS) is required to get any data from Wikipedia. Long story short, I am able to parse this data and push it to an array.

And I have a nice array of objects that I should be able to iterate through with ng-repeat... but nothing is happening. Here is the link to that pen, or you can look at the code below: 
http://codepen.io/StephenMayeux/pen/WQRawr

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('wikipedia', []);

  app.controller('WikiController', ['$http','$scope', function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.search = { text: '' };
    var api = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=';
    var apiEnding = '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
    var pageUrl = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=';


    $scope.search = function() {
      var final = [];
      $http.jsonp(api + $scope.search.text + apiEnding).success(function(data) {
        var results = data.query.pages 
        angular.forEach(results, function(v,k) {
          final.push({title: v.title, body: v.extract, page: pageUrl + v.pageid})
        })
        console.log(final);

      });
    };    
  }]);

})();

<html ng-app="wikipedia">

<body ng-controller="WikiController">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Wikipedia Search Engine</h1>
    <form class="form-inline" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="searchInWikipedia">Search Wikipedia by using this textbox</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.text" placeholder="What do you want to learn about today?">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Search</span></button>
    </form>
    <div >
      <div id="search-results" ng-repeat="key in final">
        <h3>{{key.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{key.body}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have:

1) checked for typos.

2) printed to the console, and I'm definitely getting an array of objects.

3) used only Angular, and no other libraries like jQuery that could potentially conflict with my code.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Seems the final variable is not a scope variable!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gambae

```
  $scope.final = [];
```

You need to add to scope the things you want to show on screen.

Comment: You were absolutely right! I tried everything and had even read the $scope documentation before I posted here. Funny thing is I didn't use $scope in my first application.

Comment: In Angular 1, that's the way, how you bind variables from controller to view... There is one more approach with syntax "controller as", but in Angular 1 world - $scope is the most conman...